# Xsane is unable to detect scanner device

Tags: linux, debian, xsane

I'm using debian lenny, I bought a new Hp officejet j4500 scanner but the xsane is unable to detect the scanner. It says device not found. If I run xsane as root it detects and works 
properly it is obvious.

I have added the user to scanner,saned and also to root user group.

Can anyone please help me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP OfficeJet J4500 should be supported by Lenny. Try this [troubleshooting procedure](http://hplipopensource.com/node/333).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [thread at the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-166944.html), I'd suggest the following:
Use `lsusb` to determine the device of your scanner, navigate to `/dev/bus/usb/$BUS/$DEVICE` and check the permissions of that device, i.e. what group it belongs to. Try to give your user the necessary groups for it, or if that fails, chmod the device (as suggested in the thread).